# How to create mapping in elasticsearch for index generated by mongo-connector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Official documentation says, we can create a mapping for `string` type for each index, named after the MongoDB database and collection names as `animals.kitten`.

I tried to create mapping as:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/animals.kitten/_mapping' -d '
{
    "animals.kitten" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
        }
    }
}'
```

But it throws the error as:

```
{
   "error": "ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;]",
   "status": 500
}
```

I dont know where I am wrong. I tried different alternatives which did not worked as well. Even though elasticsearch generate dynamic mapping for each field in index `animals.kitten`, it would be great if I could manually insert the mapping.

Comment: Not something I have been using lately. But from memory I  don't think the "database/collection" relation can be specified with "dot notation" like this. I think the "river" config marks the database and collection for an endpoint like "/kittens" then you configure the mapping.

Comment: But in mongo-connector, it has been clearly specified that the elasticsearch index name will be like animals.kitten [where animals is database name and kitten is collection name].

Comment: This is what I told your "answerer" as well. And I am sure it cannot be done like that. There are different name spacing rules.

Comment: Yes there is rules. But what mongo-connector is implementing is different. And I am not sure how to update mapping, whereas animals.kitten/_mapping works well.

Comment: So for future reference, how about adding that sort of information in your initial question rather than waiting for people to ask you and then wait hours for it. Okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry For the late answer but I found the way to do the mapping. The example of mapping is:

```
    curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/animals.kitten/string/_mapping" -d'{
        "string": {
            "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
             }
         }
     }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index name is missing and your type name is inconsistent (missing the last "s").  This works:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/animals.kittens/_mapping' -d '
{
  "animals.kittens" : {
    "properties" : {
        "name" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
    }
  }
}'
```

(you need to create the index first though)

Comment: Probably a temporary comment as a prompter. But perhaps a corresponding "river" definition for "myindex" would make this a much clearer statement. And please correct my comment in the answer if "dot" defined collection names that are not "database.collection" are supported. I hope they are, but the additional information could make this a good answer.

Comment: "animals.kittens" will work fine as a type name in Elasticsearch - the typo and missing index just needs to be fixed. I don't know that @BlackRabbitt is using a river - he's not mentioned this in his question.

Comment: The OP did not mention (and BTW you cannot "tag" someone not in the stream of comments) if they meant "database.collection" either. But it would be nice to have a full bodied answer that explained that rather than answering to me. Don't you think?

Comment: I am NOT using river, perhaps I am using mongo-connector. Sorry for typo, it is just typing mistake. And @Olly Cruickshank, animals.kitten (with or without "s") is actually a index name created by mongo-connector equivalent to mongodb database.collection. When searching for mapping with: localhost:9200/animals.kitten/_mapping, I can see the mapping. Problem is with updating mapping. Elasticsearch is not providing me the way to update mapping in index animals.kitten as mentioned above in question.

Comment: A mapping needs both an index and a type - this is why you get the `mapping type is missing` error. I'm surprised that a get on localhost:9200/animals.kitten/_mapping returns anything - possibly this is a bug?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. GET localhost:9200.animals.kitten/_mapping works but PUT doesnot work.